# synthesizeToFile failed in Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

TextToSpeech is initialized like this in onCreate()

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

onInit coded like this.

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(String s) {
                Log.v(TAG, "onStart : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String s) {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                fabSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                Log.v(TAG, "Proceed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String s) {
                Log.v(TAG, "onError : " + s);
            }
        });
        Log.v(TAG, "Proceed2");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Initilization Failed!");
    }
}
```

only Proceed2 printed. Proceed is printed only on when I call

```
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "1");
```

If I synthesizeToFile without call speak like this

```
int test = tts.synthesizeToFile(text, null, file, "tts");
if (test == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Success");
}
```

This log prints Success, but file is empty. If I synthesize file after called speak then file has data.

But I want to synthesizeToFile without call speak. I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: How long are you waiting before you check if the file is empty? It can take a while to synthesise and waiting for `onDone` to be called is the correct way to check it is complete.

Comment: @brandall onDone never called, if I synthesise before calling speak. Thats is the issue for me :(

Comment: Are using `QUEUE_FLUSH` on the speak request and therefore cancelling the synthesis before it has had a chance to complete?